# Pasar valor a Input Text

Tags: javascript, html5, php7

Buen día, paso por aquí solicitando su ayuda. Tengo un input select que trae datos de mi BD, el cual lo ocupo para traer información de mi BD respecto al valor que se haya seleccionado.

El problema que tengo es que esa información la obtengo mediante un ID que esta en un "div", y yo quisiera ponerlo como valor de un input.

No se si me logre explicar pero aqui dejo mi codigo html donde obtengo los datos de mi select

```html
<select class="custom-select select2 personal" name="persona" required>
  <option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>
  <?php                                             
     while($ru=mysqli_fetch_array($persona)){
       echo '<option value='.$ru['id'].'>'.$ru['nombre'].' '.$ru['apellidoP'].' '.$ru['apellidoM'].'</option>';
      }
  ?>
</select>
```

y este es mi código JS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".personal").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    var dataString = 'empid=' + id;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'getPersonal',
      dataType: "json",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(employeeData) {
        if (employeeData) {
          $("#emp_nombre").value(employeeData.nombre);

        }
      }
    });
  })
});
```

espero y puedan apoyarme, los datos los obtengo bien, solo quiero que en lugar de que ese dato se muestre en un div, se muestre en un input

Comment: No. No logras explicarte. Obtienes el `id` de un `<div/>`. Quieres mostrar un resultado en un `<input/>`? Veo que tienes un `select` con los `id` de personas. Veo que cuando cambia el select traes la información de la persona con ese id. Pero, no entiendo tu problema/pregunta...

Comment: Si, mira una vez que selecciono a una persona los datos que trae son como su edad, etc. pero los muestro en etiquetas div, y lo que quiero es que se muestren en inputs .

Comment: Y... cuál es el problema? qué problema hay con `$('#nombrePersona').val(employeeData.nombre);`? Será porque usas `.value()` en lugar de `.val()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

estas usando jQuery y para poner un valor debes usar `val()`:

`$("#emp_nombre").val(employeeData.nombre);`

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió.!

Answer (score 1):

```
var mostrarIdUsuario = $(".idUsuario").text();
$("#actualizarIdUsuario").val(mostrarIdUsuario);
```

Puedes generar una variable y hacer que ese dato se muestre en el text donde lo quieres.